# Accessing specific values in a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, leaflet

I have a nested object which looks like the below

```
{
    "Place One": {
        primary: "#000000",
        secondary: "#97233f",
        coordinates: {
            lat: 49.5013,
            lon: 87.0622
        }
    },
    "Place Two": {
        primary: "#000000",
        secondary: "#a71930",
        coordinates: {
            lat: 40.6013,
            lon: 81.0622
        }
    },
    "Place Three": {
        primary: "#9e7c0c",
        secondary: "#241773",
        coordinates: {
            lat: 40.5033,
            lon: 84.0622
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get access to each of the lat /lon variables to pass to a Leaflet React component

```
 <Marker
          key={park.properties.PARK_ID}
          position={[
            ***the lat***,
            ***the lon***
          ]}
        
        />
```

I've tried the below:

```
Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(teams).map(([key, { coordinates }]) => <Marker
                    position={[
                        coordinates.lat,
                        coordinates.lon
                    ]} />
                )
```

but cannot access the values.

can anyone please advise the best way to do this?

Comment: why do you have Object.fromEntries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data structure containing your nested objects is assigned to a "data" variable:

```js
const data = {
  "Place One": {}, // etc.
}
```

Then in your React component template, you can loop over the "nested objects" with:

```
Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const nestedObject = data[key]
  return (<Marker
    key={key}
    position={nestedObject.coordinates} // or [nestedObject.coordinates.lat, nestedObject.coordinates.lon]
  />)
})
```

Comment: i think in the OP's code if the whole Object.fromEntries wrapping is removed it should still work?

Comment: @cmgchess yes, you're right.   const newObj = Object.entries(team).map(([key, { coordinates }]) => 
[coordinates.lat,coordinates.lon]
) works

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you should destructurate the nested object starting like this

```
const obj1 = your_nested_object
const lat = obj1.Place_One.coordinates.lat
const lon = obj1.Place_One.coordinates.lon
```